# Android glitch when opening DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, visual-glitch

I have this glitch on NEXUS 5 - 6.0.1 and NEXUS 4 - 5.1.1
The normal screenshots are from sony xperia z3 compact - 5.1.1

The Layout has nothing spécial, I'm displaying a android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment and loading an image with Glide

This is the style of the dialog:

```
<style name="liteMode.Dialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog" >
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```

When the two button are pushed I open the keyboard, it makes a layout visible (an EditText + an image on top)

As you can see the Edittext is duplicated several times with the rest of the ui. What's going on here ?

[image: Normal 1]
[image: Normal 2]
[image: Bug keyboard closed]
[image: Bug keyboard open]

Comment: a `DialogFragment` is not even intended to be used as full-screen view.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because DialogFragment is rebuilded.Please add   android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" in tag activity in AndroidManifest